# Python error when trying to compile from source

Tags: compiling

I am trying to compile from source AWN https://launchpad.net/awn/ on Xubuntu 16.04 but when i run ./configure i get:

```
configure: error: 
  Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
  installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
  via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
  Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
  ============================================================================
   ERROR!
   You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
   for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
  ============================================================================
```

I run `sudo apt-get install python-dev` but it said that it is already the newset version. What should i do?

Comment: It appears to pass that check on my 16.04 box (although it fails after that on `pygtk-2.0`). What is the result of `pkg-config --cflags --libs python`?

Comment: This is the output `-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7 -lpython2.7`